# generate a list in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

trying to generate a list of genres with the number of tracks and the % of tracks belonging to that genre. No of tracks should be order ascending.

Output should look something like this with 3 seperate columns.

```
Genre   No.of Tracks    % of Tracks 
Rock       5               20% 


Genre table consists of - GenreId , Name 

Track table consists of - TrackId, Name, GenreId
```

Comment: What code have you done, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: You should mention your table structure details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/053e1a/2)

```
SELECT g.nameOfGenre,
  COUNT(t.TrackId) AS tracks_count,
  COUNT(t.TrackId) / tt.total_tracks * 100 AS tracks_percent
FROM Genre g
  LEFT JOIN Track t ON t.GenreId = g.genreId
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_tracks FROM Track) AS tt
GROUP BY g.genreId
```

Simple example. You can round percents if you want.

Comment: what does track_count resemble

Comment: It is "No.of Tracks" in your notation :-) How many tracks are presented with this genre. "tracks_percent" is "% of Tracks".

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give it a test and let you know how it goes :)!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: After seeing the OP's comment, I believe the following query should be more suitable. Unlike the answer below me, I will use an implicit join.

```
SELECT Genre.genreName, Track.trackName, COUNT(Track.genreID) AS "Track Count", ( ( (COUNT(Track.genreID) / COUNT(Track.trackID)) * 100 ) AS "Percent Of Tracks") FROM Genre, Track WHERE Genre.genreID = Track.genreID;
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Assuming that these are all in the same table, this can be achieved with a simple     SELECT   query.

```
SELECT Genre, No_Of_Tracks, Percent_of_Tracks FROM Table ORDER BY No_Of_Tracks
```

You should replace "Genre, No_Of_Tracks, Percent_Of_Tracks" with your respective column names and Table with the actual table name.

Comment: sorry I didn't write the question properly i should have specified

Comment: @M.Jones Might I ask what's the specific name of the Genre and Track tables? Furthermore, is the G in GenreID meant to be capitalized in the Track table?

Comment: This will not work. You even don't have `GROUP BY` in query - it will return only ONE row. But we need one row per genre.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below query

```
 Select g.nameOfGenre as Genre, count(t.trackId) as "No.of Tracks", 
        concat(round(count(t.trackId)/tt.total_tracks * 100, 2),'%')  as "% of Tracks" 
 from Track t
 join Genre g on g.genreID = t.genreID
 join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_tracks FROM Track) AS tt
 group by g.genreID
```

Comment: This will not work. For each genre will be 100% tracks.

Comment: @Andrew, agree with you, update my ans, upvoted yours. Thanks